# How do I get output of release pipeline via REST method

Tags: azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-rest-api

I want to return some information to calling application from release pipeline. I can not figure out how to return this information via REST API. I can create releases and Get release via REST API but I don't see any option to pull information about output variables.
My code is as follows

```
$random = Get-Random
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=SQL_connection_string]$random"
```

I'm not sure what parameter/property I shall be accessing on Azure DevOps REST API endpoint to get this information
I'm pulling current release values via 
`https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{org}/02c5043e-ff46-40ed-84e4-173fdc1cca0e/_apis/Release/releases/42` as example and this values are still represented as code. Nowhere in API call to `_apis/Release/releases/{ReleaseID}` this values are showing up as actual output values

```
{
                            "environment": {},
                            "taskId": "72a1931b-effb-4d2e-8fd8-f8472a07cb62",
                            "version": "4.*",
                            "name": "Pull connection information",
                            "refName": "ReferenceNameFromAzureDevops",
                            "enabled": true,
                            "alwaysRun": false,
                            "continueOnError": false,
                            "timeoutInMinutes": 20,
                            "definitionType": "task",
                            "overrideInputs": {},
                            "condition": "succeeded()",
                            "inputs": {
                                "ConnectedServiceNameARM": "e47fa59c-c3e0-4d71-a516-0aa132de28bc",
                                "ScriptType": "InlineScript",
                                "ScriptPath": "",
                                "Inline": "$random = Get-Random\nWrite-Output \"##vso[task.setvariable variable=SQL_connection_string]$random\"\nWrite-Output \"##vso[task.setvariable variable=SQLFromReleaseVariable]$random\"\n\n\n",
                                "ScriptArguments": "",
                                "errorActionPreference": "stop",
                                "FailOnStandardError": "false",
                                "TargetAzurePs": "LatestVersion",
                                "CustomTargetAzurePs": "",
                                "pwsh": "false",
                                "workingDirectory": ""
                            }
                        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is defined in your release pipeline definition.

```
GET https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/definitions/{definitionId}?api-version=5.1
```

You could get a release pipeline with above [Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1).

From the returned JSON, you will be able to see related information under `steps`.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I might have asked this question incorrectly. I modified original code to reflect it correctly. I need to be able to read value of variable which was not statically assigned in a code (as you can see in updated code). How I retrieve it?

Comment: @GregorySuvalian Thanks for the detail explanation. It's not able to use any  parameter/property when accessing on Azure DevOps REST API endpoint  to get that variable value. This variable will only exist during the job. When job finished in pipeline, life-cycle of that variable will also end. As a workaround, you could directly use `Write-Host "$(SQL_connection_string)"` to print out the value. Then get it through logs.